# Meteor.update with a found _id not this._id

Tags: meteor, collections

I am trying to use Meteor.update by finding the Id through pulling the first obj in a list that I find. Please see the code below. I am more than happy to look at another post if we have one that will help out.

```
minusSkip: function(){
  var techQOrder = _Techs.find({
      queue: true
    }, {
      sort: {
        status: -1,
        // weight: -1,
        timesincelast: 1}});
        techQOrder = techQOrder.fetch()[0]

        var techId = techQOrder._id
        if (techQOrder.skipRound >= 1) {
  _Techs.update({
    id: techQOrder._id
  },
  {
      $set: {
        timesincelast: new Date()
      },
      $inc: {
        skipRound: -1
      }
    });
console.log("server", techQOrder._id, techQOrder.skipRound);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use findOne instead of find - simply returns the first document it finds. Then get your id:

```
techQOrder._id;
```

If for some reason you want to avoid findOne, you can add .fetch() at the end of your query and then get id by

```
techQOrder[0]._id
```

Comment: I don't think that I can use the findOne because I want to sort the collection and than pull the first obj out of that collection and edit it. The main goal is to make skip mechanism. this is part of a rotating queue and I would like to keep the integrity of the order but have it auto skip this person when they are at the top of the queue.  this is the code that checks them and they move through the queue.

Comment: In that case findOne is still works - your collection is still being sorted, but you access only the first document

Comment: and as far as I understand, that's exactly what you're trying to achieve